# Пунктуация. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

***Нет, разве что, путь от кресла и до дивана.***

Правильно расставлены запятые?

Answer (score 1):

> *Нет, разве что путь от кресла и до дивана.*

После *"нет"* запятая нужна, смотрите у [Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm):

Слова ***да*** и ***нет,*** выражающие утверждение и отрицание, отделяются в составе предложения запятой, например: ***Да,** пройдут десятки лет, и из памяти никогда не изгладятся дороги войны* (Бабаевский); *В лице Анатолия было выражение душевной силы, **да,** именно силы* (Фадеев); *Я с этим согласен, **да, да!*** (Н. Островский); ***Нет,** я не больна, Афанасий Иванович* (Гоголь); ***Нет,** в то время у меня не было никакой охоты унестись с земли на Луну или на Марс* (Паустовский).

При этом *"разве что"* вводным словом вовсе не является, поэтому вторая ваша запятая не нужна.